# Kill child process while waiting for it

Tags: rust

I want to execute another process and normally want to wait until it has finished. Lets say we spawn and wait for the process in thread T1:

```
let child = Command::new("rustc").spawn().unwrap();
child.wait();
```

Now, if a special event occurs (which thread T0 is waiting for) I want to kill the spawned process:

```
if let Ok(event) = special_event_notifier.recv() {
    child.kill();
}
```

But I don't see a way to do it: both `kill` and `wait` take a mutable reference to `Child` and are therefore mutually exclusive. After calling `wait` no one can have any reference to `child` anymore.

I've found the [`wait-timeout`](https://github.com/alexcrichton/wait-timeout) crate, but I want to know if there's another way.

Comment: Hm, this seems to be a good question to ask in the issue tracker.

Comment: Busy waiting with [`Child::try_wait()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html#method.try_wait) is possible since Rust 1.18. But that doesn't really solve the problem...

Answer (score 4):

If the child subprocess do not close stdout before finishing, it's possible to wait reading stdout. Here is an example

```
use std::io::Read;
use std::process::*;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn wait_on_output(mut out: ChildStdout) {
    while out.read_exact(&mut [0; 1024]).is_ok() { }
}

fn wait_or_kill(cmd: &mut Command, max: Duration) {
    let mut child = cmd.stdout(Stdio::piped())
                       .spawn()
                       .expect("Cannot spawn child");

    let out = child.stdout.take().expect("No stdout on child");

    let h = thread::spawn(move || {
        thread::sleep(max);
        child.kill().expect("Cannot kill child");
        println!("{:?}", child.wait());
    });

    wait_on_output(out);
    h.join().expect("join fail");
}

fn main() {
    wait_or_kill(Command::new("sleep").arg("1"), Duration::new(2, 0));
    wait_or_kill(Command::new("sleep").arg("3"), Duration::new(2, 0));
}
```

The output of this program on my system is

```
Ok(ExitStatus(ExitStatus(0)))
Ok(ExitStatus(ExitStatus(9)))
```

Although not in the docs, killing a finished child returns `Ok`.

This works because killing a process close the files associated with it. However, if the child spawn new processes, killing the child may not kill these other processes and they may keep the stdout opened.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, you can just kill the process yourself. The `Child::id` method gives you the "OS-assigned process identifier" that should be sufficient for that.

The only problem is that killing a process is a platform-dependent action. On UNIX killing a process is handled with the [kill](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html) function:

```
#![feature(libc)]
extern crate libc;
use std::env::args;
use std::process::Command;
use std::thread::{spawn, sleep};
use std::time::Duration;
use libc::{kill, SIGTERM};

fn main() {
    let mut child = Command::new("/bin/sh").arg("-c").arg("sleep 1; echo foo").spawn().unwrap();
    let child_id = child.id();
    if args().any(|arg| arg == "--kill") {
        spawn(move || {
            sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
            unsafe {
                kill(child_id as i32, SIGTERM);
            }
        });
    }
    child.wait().unwrap();
}
```

On Windows you might try the [OpenProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [TerminateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions (available with the [kernel32-sys](https://crates.io/crates/kernel32-sys/) crate).

Answer (score 0):

The [`shared_child`](https://crates.io/crates/shared_child) crate solves this exact problem.