# Interfacing with a std::process::Child from different threads

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm making a little supervisor to manage long-running processes. Currently I'm using `std::process::Command` with `.spawn()` to get a `std::process::Child`.

What I want to achieve is: have one thread `.wait()`ing on this Child (eventually returning a message on a channel), and another waiting on a channel for a "KILL" message, which will then call `.kill()` on the Child.

Child, however, isn't `Clone`, and both `.wait()` and `.kill()` are `&mut self`... so am I out of luck? I don't think I can use mutexes since the `.wait()` needs to block.

Current PoC is here...

```
use std::process::{Command};

fn main() {
    let child = Command::new("long_running_process")
                        .arg("something_something")
                        .spawn().unwrap();

    // now, I want to have two threads; one doing child.wait(), one waiting on a mpsc or ZMQ
    // channel to get a "KILL" message.

    // This doesn't work.
    {
        let sub_child = child.clone();
        std::thread::spawn(move || {
            sub_child.wait();
        });
    }
    // repro.rs:13:31: 13:36 error: no method named `clone` found for type `std::process::Child` in the current scope
    // repro.rs:13         let sub_child = child.clone();
    //                                           ^~~~~
    // repro.rs:15:13: 15:29 error: the type of this value must be known in this context
    // repro.rs:15             sub_child.wait();
    //                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
}
```

Comment: I asked pretty much exactly the same without satisfying answer :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093869/kill-child-process-while-waiting-for-it

Comment: I'm afraid there is no non-blocking wait or wait with timeout for child termination. You can consider other IPC mechanisms to signal the termination of a child, and have parent wait on both that IPC mechanism and the kill message.

Comment: ah! I missed that in my searching somehow :( sad news, I'll have to dig deeper.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt do you think the two questions are duplicates?

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes I think so. I wasn't able to flag it since my thread doesn't have an accepted answer. Boop: There is more information [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1294) and [here](https://github.com/passcod/cargo-watch/issues/25). There were also [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1359) RFC which added two methods. Maybe those are helpful.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt ah, good point. We'll have to watch both and hope for an answer on one :-)

Comment: I have write an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093869/kill-child-process-while-waiting-for-it