# How to query a child process status regularly

Tags: rust

I have spawned a child process using Rust's [Command](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) API.

Now, I need to watch this process for a few seconds before moving on because the process may die early. On success, it should run "forever", so I can't just wait.

There's a nightly feature called [try_wait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html#method.try_wait) which does what I want, but I really don't think I should run Rust nightly just for this!

I think I could start a new thread and keep it waiting forever or until the process dies... but I would like to not hang my process with that thread, so maybe run the thread as a daemon might be a solution...

Is this the way to go or is there a nicer solution?

Comment: You may want an async event-loop; `tokio-process` handles this beautifully, but requires full code refactor.

Comment: [`wait-timeout`](https://github.com/alexcrichton/wait-timeout) could help. Also: [maybe related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093869/kill-child-process-while-waiting-for-it).

Comment: wait-timeout is perfect! Thanks.. @TatsuyukiIshi tokio looks nice, but all I need now is a timeout waiting, that seems overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, if you don't want to use the nightly channel, there's a crate called [wait-timeout](https://docs.rs/wait-timeout/0.1.5/wait_timeout/) (thanks to @lukas-kalbertodt for the suggestion) that adds the `wait_timeout` function to the [`std::process::Child`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html) trait.

It can be used like this:

```
let cmd = Command::new("my_command")
    .spawn();

match cmd {
    Ok(mut child) => {
        let timeout = Duration::from_secs(1);

        match child.wait_timeout(timeout) {
            Ok(Some(status)) => println!("Exited with status {}", status),
            Ok(None) => println!("timeout, process is still alive"),
            Err(e) => println!("Error waiting: {}", e),
        }
    }
    Err(err) => println!("Process did not even start: {}", err);
}
```

To keep monitoring the child process, just wrap this into a loop.

Notice that using Rust's nightly [`try_wait()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html#method.try_wait), the code would looks nearly identical (so once it makes into the release branch, assuming no further changes, it should be very easy to move to that), but it will block for the given `timeout` even if the process dies earlier than that, unlike with the above solution:

```
let cmd = Command::new("my_command")
    .spawn();

match cmd {
    Ok(mut child) => {
        let timeout = Duration::from_secs(1);
        sleep(timeout); // try_wait will not block, so we need to wait here
        match child.try_wait() {
            Ok(Some(status)) => println!("Exited with status {}", status),
            Ok(None) => println!("timeout, process is still alive"),
            Err(e) => println!("Error waiting: {}", e),
        }
    }
    Err(err) => println!("Process did not even start: {}", err);
}
```

Comment: Err(e) => println!("Error waiting: {}", e); should be Err(e) => println!("Error waiting: {}", e),