# How do I make sure that file handle for every `Child` process is released after every iteration?

Tags: rust, file-descriptor, systems-programming

I have the following program taken [from the Rust docs for `std::process::Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html). It stops working after some iterations.

```
use std::process::Command;
use std::process::Stdio;

fn main() {
    loop {
        let mut echo_child = Command::new("echo")
            .arg("oh no a tpyo")
            .stdout(Stdio::piped())
            .spawn()
            .expect("failed to start 'echo'");

        let echo_out = echo_child.stdout.expect("failed to open 'echo' stdout");

        let sed_child = Command::new("sed")
            .arg("s/tpyo/typo/")
            .stdin(Stdio::from(echo_out))
            .stdout(Stdio::piped())
            .spawn()
            .expect("failed to start 'sed'");

        let sed_out = sed_child
            .wait_with_output()
            .expect("failed to wait on 'sed'");
        let sed_out_slice = sed_out.stdout.as_slice();
        assert_eq!(b"oh no a typo\n", sed_out_slice);
        println!("out: {:?}", String::from_utf8_lossy(sed_out_slice));
    }
}
```

Every time it crashes, I receive the following output:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'failed to start 'sed': Error { repr: Os { code: 35, message: "Resource temporarily unavailable" } }', src/libcore/result.rs:906:4
```

According to [the docs for `Child`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html) (where I took this program from), it says:

> There is no implementation of `Drop` for child processes, so if you do
>   not ensure the `Child` has exited then it will continue to run, even
>   after the `Child` handle to the child process has gone out of scope.

How do I make sure that file handle for every `Child` process is released after every iteration?

Comment: This code does **not** come from [the Rust docs for `Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html). Which docs are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the paragraph immediately after the one you have quoted:

> Calling `wait` (or other functions that wrap around it) will make the parent process wait until the child has actually exited before continuing.

In order to call `wait`, you need to not move `stdout` out of `Child`:

```
let echo_out = echo_child.stdout.take().expect("failed to open 'echo' stdout");

// ...

echo_child.wait().expect("Couldn't wait for echo child");
```

See also:

- [Kill child process while waiting for it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35093869/155423)