# How can I use stored child process var in struct after it's been assigned to self?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I want to store a child process in a struct and be able to run functions "start_process" and "kill_process". I want to have it in a asynchronous function to potentially be able to spawn multiple processes at the same time and get the status as they exit.

```rust
use std::{error::Error, process::Stdio};
use tokio::{
    io::{AsyncBufReadExt, BufReader},
    process::{self, Child},
};
pub struct ProcessHandler {
    child: Option<Child>,
}

impl ProcessHandler {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { child: None }
    }

    pub async fn kill_process(mut self) {
        if let Some(mut child) = self.child.take() {
            child.kill().await.expect("Failed to kill child process");
        }
    }

    pub async fn start_process(&mut self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
        let mut child = process::Command::new("ping")
            .arg("8.8.8.8")
            .stdout(Stdio::piped())
            .spawn()
            .expect("Couldn't run 'ping'");

        self.child = Some(child); // <--- child is moved here

        let mut reader = BufReader::new(child.stdout.take().unwrap()).lines();

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let status = child
                .wait()
                .await
                .expect("child process encountered an error");

            println!("child status was: {}", status);
        });

        while let Some(line) = reader.next_line().await? {
            println!("line:{:?}", line);
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

How should I write my code to not get the move of the child variable when setting `self.child = Some(child)`?

Now I get the error message: borrow of moved value: `child` value borrowed here after move

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre] including, use statements, custom types, the *full* error message?

Comment: I think the question [Kill child process while waiting for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093869/kill-child-process-while-waiting-for-it) is pretty much a duplicate of this one since they both are trying to do the same thing: kill a process while awaiting its termination, which isn't possible since both `wait()` and `kill()` require an exclusive borrow.